# Why does JsonConvert returns null on key's that start with "/"? Like "/User"?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have some json and some keys start with a "/", after JsonConvert those objects that start with "/" are null...

Json sample:

```
 [
{
    "/user": {
        "id": "someid",
        "firstname": "firstname",
        "lastname": "firstname",
        "age": "age",
        "location": "location"
    },
    "country": {
        "id": "countryid",
        "name": "countryname"
    }
}
```

]

This are the classes:

```
 public class UserObject
 {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "/user")]
    public User _User { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "country")]
    public Country _Country { get; set; }
 }

 public class User
 {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "firstname")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "lastname")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "age")]
    public string Age { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "location")]
    public string Location { get; set; }
  }

  public class Country
  {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "country")]
    public string Country_ { get; set; }
  }
```

So after JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json) the object User is null but Country is filled up with values.

How do you handle "/" in C#?

Comment: What does the object look like that you're deserialising to?  Since `/user` isn't a valid C# property name, you'll need some sort of mapping between your JSON and your classes...

Comment: @JamesThorpe edited.

Comment: How do you call the `Deserialize` method?

Comment: @SteveB UserObjectList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserObject>>(json);

Comment: where json is the data that comes from a uri

Comment: Please provide a minimal self-contained code example that actually reproduces the problem.  The code you've given does not compile (class named `Country` with property named `Country` is illegal), but when I fix that one thing, everything works including population of `_User` from `/user`

Comment: Your code will not compile - you can't have a `Country` property on a `Country` class.  If I fix that error I'm able to load your json just fine.

Comment: @DStanley   yes it compiles, but it returns null for "/User" object

Comment: It compiles _after_ you change the `Country` property name, but it still doesn't map to the json (json has a `name` property for `country`. But something else is wrong - I just used the exact class definition and josn string you provide and I get a valid User object.  How are you validating that it's null?

Comment: Are you passing in the `UserObject` type to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`?

Comment: @DStanley ok I found out it has nothing to do with the "/" in the headertages, the error is coming from a convert null to int32. :P

Comment: @Bayern, if you find the solution, answer to your own question, in order to mark it as solved.